# Kinova Arm can not be converted from urdf using urdf2webots tool

Tags: ros, webots

I am trying to convert a URDF of a kinova arm into the PROTO format. The issue I have is that when I import the PROTO into Webots all the joints are rotated at weird angles. The URDF I am converting is the m1n6s300_standalone.xacro from [kinova-ros](https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros) converted to URDF using ROS. See below an image of the broken file.

See [image here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26240969/50626497-61a2d980-0f7a-11e9-9634-b4722ba21790.png)

I have imported the URDF into other robotic simulators in the past so I don't believe something is inherently wrong with the file, more like something is wrong with the converter.

Answer (score 0):

The URDF importer is still under development, you can find the source code here: https://github.com/omichel/urdf2webots
Do not hesitate to contribute. Or open an issue with the file you are trying to convert (m1n6s300_standalone.xacro) and explain step by step the procedure your are following and the problem you are facing and when someone will have time he will look at it.

Comment: Thanks David, I have opened an issue.